# The correct way to create an HTMLDocument using HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

Consider the code below:

```
string url="http://badoo.com";
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
```

Now I have the htmlstring inside the result variable, let's try something:

```
// save normally
File.WriteAllText("1.html",result);

// save using HTMLAgilityPack
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
hdoc.LoadHtml(result);
hdoc.Save("2.html");
```

Can someone please tell me why 1.html and 2.html doesn't look the same ? Although they have the same file size ?

Link to the correct one (file.writealltext() ) : http://woman2.com/1.html

Link to the  wrong one (saved with htmlagility pack) : http://woman2.com/2.html

**Update:** 
I have also tried to save the file on local disk and then

```
hdoc.Load("path/to/local",true);
```

I have also tried:

```
hdoc.LoadHtml(result);
```

And tried:

```
hdoc.Save("2.html",Encoding.UTF8);
```

but any of the attemps seems to be working to me. I've been struggling with this for 3 days now.

Comment: What do you mean "don't look the same"? We aren't at your computer, we don't know what the files look like. Perhaps you should load a small document as an example and then post the differences.

Comment: First you ought to make your 1.html valid as HTML. You can use something like the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to help with that. Also, putting new line characters in would make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Morton is correct.  The file '1.html' is formed in a way that makes agility pack angry/scared/confused.  In all seriousness,  I ran your code and diffed the resulting files and here are some of the differences:

---

Innocuous:

- removes whitespace redundancy
- adds closing tags where were previously self-closing

Possibly affect the site:

- adds attribute values where none previously existed
- changes language-specific characters

Likely affect the site:

- "fixes" unmatched quotations (I would put my money here if I had to guess)

---

Again, as Andrew mentioned, fix that up first before banging your head against the wall any further.